# What do you call the decimal part of a decimal?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call the decimal part of a decimal? Is it "decimal values"?

> 3.**14159**

Answer (score 1):

Formally, it's sometimes called the [**mantissa**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html), but I don't think anyone except math professors ever says that.  The most common terms are [**fractional part**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html) or **decimal part**.

For example,

> [The decimal point together with the digits lying on the right of decimal point form the decimal part.](https://www.math-only-math.com/decimal-numbers.html)

> [The part from the decimal separator to the right is the fractional part...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#Decimal_notation)

"Decimal value**s**" would be confusing because it sounds like it's referring to more than one value, and something like ".314159" is only one value.